# How to get Metadata during build session factory

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-annotations, spring-orm

Using Spring 4.3.4 & Hibernate 5.1.17

I want to know how to modify metadata or get entity mapping metadata at runtime.
Can i extend LocalSessionFactoryBean, getMetadata and modify it to use different schema ?
All i want to do is, i need to replace table name from schema2 to mock_schema2.

As part of dbtest, i need to use different schema instead of normal schema which is used in entity definition.
When i use below entity definition

```
    @ Table(name = “cluster”, schema = “schema1”)
    @ SecondaryTable(name = “Cluster”, schema = “schema2”, pkJoinColumns = @ PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = “clusterId”, referencedColumnName = “objid”))
    @ org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo = “Cluster”, optional = false)
    @ Entity
    @ OptimisticLocking(type = OptimisticLockType.DIRTY)
    @ DynamicUpdate
    public class Cluster implements Serializable {

    }
```

Hibernate internally generates query as below

```
select
        this_.objid as objid1_0_0_,
        this_.name as name2_0_0_,
        this_.resourceKey as resource3_0_0_,
        this_.uuid as uuid4_0_0_,
        this_1_.healthStatus as healthSt1_2_0_,
        this_1_.lastSync as lastSync2_2_0_
    from
        schema1.cluster this_
    inner join
        schema2.Cluster this_1_
            on this_.objid=this_1_.clusterId;
```

In case of Dbtest, i want **the query to use mock_schema2.Cluster instead of schema2.Cluster**.
I want to know how to do that without modifying entity definition

https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-get-access-to-database-table-metadata-with-hibernate-5/
Basically, I am trying to follow the way mentioned in the above blog.

Comment: Can someone please tell me how to update schema from the entity at runtime?

Comment: Refer to this https://shekhargulati.com/2018/01/09/programmatically-generating-database-schema-with-hibernate-5/